# Random NuGet packages in Azure Artifacts

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, nuget, nuget-package, azure-artifacts

I have a CI/CD Pipeline that builds a .NET Core Solution, containing multiple Class Library Projects, to build NuGet Packages. These NuGet packages are stored in a Feed in Azure Artifacts. Works fine.

But somehow there are a lot of other packages stored in there, which are not from me or from the pipeline? NuGet Packages from different repos (CsvHelper, Azure.Identity,...)

How is that possible?

Comment: Does your feed have an upstream source configured? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/concepts/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops

Comment: @zivkan Yes, I have NuGet Gallery inside Upstream Sources

Comment: @zivkan, but If I disable them, my CI/CD won't work, because they need some packages from NuGet

Comment: yes, but Azure Artifacts is working as expected. When it sources a pacakge from nuget.org, it saves the copy in your feed.

Comment: Ok and how can I get rid of them ?

Comment: You can get rid of that via creating a new feed and add the old feed as new feed's upstream source.

Comment: Hi bbrinck, is there any update for this issue? I've confirmed that my workaround can resolve your issue on my side. Could you please check that and feel free to let me know if it's helpful?

Answer (score 2):

What you encountered is an **expected behavior** which is documented in official document.

**You can check this [Note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/nuget/upstream-sources?view=azure-devops#enable-the-upstream-on-an-existing-feed):**

*Enabling the nuget.org upstream source on a widely-used feed can result in unexpected packages being saved into that feed.*

*Once you enable the nuget.org upstream source, any that runs a package request against your feed can save packages from nuget.org into your feed. If you've distributed your feed URL to a large set of consumers, this means that users outside your team could save packages you weren't expecting into your feed.*

**To get rid of them:**

1.If you're concerned about this, consider creating a new feed then adding nuget.org and your current feed as upstream sources to that newly created feed.

2.Or just filter to own packages via the filter with `This feed` option:

[image]